# How to use the not selector correctly in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I understand the basic gist of using :not() in CSS, but it doesn't seem to work for me.  I am trying to do something like:

```
input[type=text][readonly]:not(.class1, .class2) {
background-color: #DDDDDD;
color: #1E1E1E;
}
```

But this does nto seem to work for me.  whenever I read any information on this, it will have examples like `input:not(.class1, .class2) {`, but nothing between the tag and the `:not()` part.  Am I correct in assuming that the syntax I have written is incorrect?  Can I not define the tag element any more if I use `:not()`?

Comment: something from chris: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/

Comment: I read through that previously, it doesnt seem to have the information I am looking for, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only issue is that you're passing two selectors inside the `:not()` use only one per statement.

Currently *extended arguments* *`(foo, bar)`* are not supported by any browser.

**Use**

```
:not(.class1):not(.class2)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot

```css
input[type=text][readonly]:not(.class1):not(.class2) {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  color: #1E1E1E;
}
```

```html
<input type=text readonly class="class1">
<input type=text readonly>
<input type=text readonly class="class2">
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that :)  I also heard that `:not()` does not work in IE, is this true?

Comment: @user3334871 only from version 9

Comment: Does that mean below version 9, or above?  I, unfortunately, have to support IE9 with my application for another year or so.

Comment: @user3334871 IE9 will be happy with the above. You can always test.

Answer (score 2):

`:not` accepts only simple selectors, and not lists of them.

So your selector should look like:

```
input[type=text][readonly]:not(.class1):not(.class2) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it combined way:

```
:not(.class1):not(.class2)
```

The `:not` selector is not a function. It is like any other selector taking in the other selector.

Your final CSS should be:

```
input[type=text][readonly]:not(.class1):not(.class2) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
input[type=text][readonly]:not(.class1):not(.class2) {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  color: #1E1E1E;
}
```

```html
<input type=text readonly class="class1">
<input type=text readonly class="class2">
<input type=text readonly>
```